# Closing a simple table in XSL for newsletters

Tags: xml, xslt

We have newsletters which are created in XSL, this allows editors to tag articles which then automatically generate newsletters. This is a relatively powerful system.

I am new to XSL and am struggling to get the newsletter to display correctly in outlook (it appears 100% fine in a web browser but I am pretty sure I know why the problems are occurring.

I understand various padding problems with newsletters but i am finding it hard to close the table - yes a simple table. I'm really not sure if anyone can help me resolve this but here we go:

I have highlighted the only problematic code. Adding `</table>` at the end of the bold section simply wont compile - it forces me to close with  `</xsl:template>` and `</xsl:stylesheet>`. This means that the italic code is being styled by the mode "top-story" but this only occurs in the email client and not the browser.

The full code is too long to post here (939 lines long) so I have created a simplified version (hopfully with not too many syntax errors)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet  [
  <!ENTITY nbsp   "&#160;">
  <!ENTITY copy   "&#169;">
  <!ENTITY reg    "&#174;">
  <!ENTITY trade  "&#8482;">
  <!ENTITY mdash  "&#8212;">
  <!ENTITY ldquo  "&#8220;">
  <!ENTITY rdquo  "&#8221;">
  <!ENTITY pound  "&#163;">
  <!ENTITY yen    "&#165;">
  <!ENTITY euro   "&#8364;">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>

  <!-- Load Utilities XSL -->
  <xsl:include href = "$xslPath/x156.xsl"/>


  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="search-results/size &gt; 0">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="search-results/items" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <p>There are no articles linked to this newsletter.</p>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="items">

    <xsl:variable name="prem1_img">
      <xsl:value-of select="document('http://www.khl-banner.com/email/world-demolition.asp')/banners/wd/banner[@slot='prem-1']/image"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="prem1_link">
      <xsl:value-of select="document('http://www.khl-banner.com/email/world-demolition.asp')/banners/wd/banner[@slot='prem-1']/link"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="prem2_img">
      <xsl:value-of select="document('http://www.khl-banner.com/email/world-demolition.asp')/banners/wd/banner[@slot='prem-2']/image"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="prem2_link">
      <xsl:value-of select="document('http://www.khl-banner.com/email/world-demolition.asp')/banners/wd/banner[@slot='prem-2']/link"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="prem3_img">
      <xsl:value-of select="document('http://www.khl-banner.com/email/world-demolition.asp')/banners/wd/banner[@slot='prem-3']/image"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="prem3_link">
      <xsl:value-of select="document('http://www.khl-banner.com/email/world-demolition.asp')/banners/wd/banner[@slot='prem-3']/link"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <table width="770" height="25" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#BD2125">
      <tr>
        <td width="10">
          <img src="http://www.khl.com/other_files/newsletters/WD-new/spacer-red.gif" alt="" width="10" height="20" />
        </td>

        <td height="25" valign="middle" class="heading">TOP STORY »</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <br></br>

    **<table width="770">


      <xsl:if test="data-item/item-links/item-link[@id=641]/items/item/@id=$current_item_id">
        <tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="data-item[item-links/item-link[@id=641]/items/item/@id=$current_item_id]" mode="top-story"/>
        </tr>
      </xsl:if>**






      *<table width="760" height="40" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#111D25">
        <br></br>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td width="10">
              <img src="http://www.khl.com/other_files/newsletters/WD-new/spacer-111d25.gif"/>
            </td>
            <td height="40" valign="middle" class="heading">DEMOLITION AND RECYCLING INTERNATIONAL NEWSLETTER »</td>
            <td width="40" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#36609F" class="heading">
              <a href="https://en-gb.facebook.com/KHLGroup%E2%80%8E"></a>
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/DemolitionandRecyclingInternational?ref=hl">
                <img src="http://www.khl.com/other_files/newsletters/WD-new/social-icon-facebook.gif"/>
              </a>
              <a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Demolition-Recycling-International/129306127144056"></a>
            </td>
            <td width="10" valign="middle" class="heading">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="40" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#2CAAE1" class="heading">
              <a href="https://twitter.com/KHLConstruction%E2%80%8E"></a>
              <a href="http://www.twitter.com/KHL_DRI">
                <img src="http://www.khl.com/other_files/newsletters/WD-new/social-icon-twitter.gif"/>
              </a>
              <a href="http://www.twitter.com/KHL_DRI"></a>
            </td>
            <td width="10" valign="middle" class="heading">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="40" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#0A6C9B" class="heading">
              <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/khl-group%E2%80%8E"></a>
              <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=3546771&amp;trk=my_groups-b-grp-v">
                <img src="http://www.khl.com/other_files/newsletters/WD-new/social-icon-linkedin.gif"/>
              </a>
              <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/groups/World-Demolition-Summit-2011-3983919?trk=myg_ugrp_ovr"></a>
            </td>
            <td width="10" valign="middle" class="heading">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="40" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#EE3537" class="heading">
              <a href="http://www.youtube.com/khlgroup">
                <img src="http://www.khl.com/other_files/newsletters/WD-new/social-icon-youtube.gif"/>
              </a>
              <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/KHLGroup/videos?view=1"></a>
            </td>
            <td width="10" valign="middle" class="heading">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="40" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F58020" class="heading">
              <a href="http://www.khl.com/feeds">
                <img src="http://www.khl.com/other_files/newsletters/WD-new/social-icon-rss.gif"/>
              </a>
            </td>
            <td width="10" valign="middle" class="heading">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>*



      <table width="70" height="10" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

        <br></br>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#666666" width="80" style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 18px; font-family: Arial,Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#bc2024; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;" title="textColor">
              <span title="textColor" style="text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;SPONSOR&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
            </td>
          </tr>



          <xsl:if test="$prem1_img != ''">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="764">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="2" height="50" align="center">
                        <!--img height="30" width="760" src="http://www.khl.com/other_files/newsletters/world-demolition/wd-sponsor.gif" /><br /-->
                        <a href="{$prem1_link}">
                          <img border="0" src="{$prem1_img}" />
                        </a>
                        <br />
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:if>


        </tbody>
      </table>


      <table width="770" height="25" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#111D25">
        <br></br>
        <tr>
          <td width="10">
            <img src="http://www.khl.com/other_files/newsletters/WD-new/spacer-111d25.gif" alt="" width="10" height="20" />
          </td>

          <td height="25" valign="middle" class="heading">DEMOLITION NEWS »</td>
        </tr>
      </table>


      -->

      <xsl:if test="$prem3_img != ''">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="764">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2" height="120" align="center">
                    <!--img height="30" width="760" src="http://www.khl.com/other_files/newsletters/world-demolition/wd-sponsor.gif" /><br /-->
                    <a href="{$prem3_link}">
                      <img border="0" src="{$prem3_img}" />
                    </a>
                    <br />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:if>

    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="data-item" mode="access-news">

    <xsl:variable name="title">
      <xsl:call-template name="replaceTitle">
        <xsl:with-param name="title" select="content/item/title"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="path">
      <xsl:call-template name="detail_path">
        <xsl:with-param name="item" select="current()"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <td width="110" valign="top" class="tumbImage">
      <a href="http://www.khl.com{$path}/{link}{$title}?nltr=rw">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="item-links/item-link[@id=466]/items/item[1]">
            <img border="0" width="110" height="80" src="http://www.khl.com{item-links/item-link[@id=466]/items/item/derived-files/preview}"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <img border="0" width="110" height="80" src="http://www.khl.com{item-links/item-link[@id=2]/items/item/derived-files/preview}"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td width="285" valign="top">
      <a class="headLineLink2" href="http://www.khl.com{$path}/{link}{$title}?nltr=rw">
        <strong>
          <xsl:value-of select="name" />
        </strong>
      </a>
      <br />
      <br />
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(content/item/standfirst,0,120)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      <xsl:text>...</xsl:text>
    </td>

  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="data-item" mode="access-news2">

    <xsl:variable name="title">
      <xsl:call-template name="replaceTitle">
        <xsl:with-param name="title" select="content/item/title"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="path">
      <xsl:call-template name="detail_path">
        <xsl:with-param name="item" select="current()"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>


    <td width="110" valign="top" class="tumbImage">
      <a href="http://www.khl.com{$path}/{link}{$title}?nltr=rw">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="item-links/item-link[@id=466]/items/item[1]">
            <img border="0" width="110" height="80" src="http://www.khl.com{item-links/item-link[@id=466]/items/item/derived-files/preview}"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <img border="0" width="110" height="80" src="http://www.khl.com{item-links/item-link[@id=2]/items/item/derived-files/preview}"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td width="300" valign="top">
      <a class="headLineLink2" href="http://www.khl.com{$path}/{link}{$title}?nltr=rw">
        <strong>
          <xsl:value-of select="name" />
        </strong>
      </a>
      <br />
      <br />
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(content/item/standfirst,0,282)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      <xsl:text>...</xsl:text>
    </td>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="data-item" mode="access-news3">

    <xsl:variable name="title">
      <xsl:call-template name="replaceTitle">
        <xsl:with-param name="title" select="content/item/title"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="path">
      <xsl:call-template name="detail_path">
        <xsl:with-param name="item" select="current()"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <tr>
      <td width="250">
        <a class="headLineLink2" href="http://www.khl.com{$path}/{link}{$title}?nltr=rw">
          <strong>
            <xsl:value-of select="name" />
          </strong>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <td width="110" valign="top" class="tumbImage">
      <a href="http://www.khl.com{$path}/{link}{$title}?nltr=rw">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="item-links/item-link[@id=466]/items/item[1]">
            <img border="0" width="110" height="80" align="left" src="http://www.khl.com{item-links/item-link[@id=466]/items/item/derived-files/preview}"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <img border="0" width="110" height="80" align="left" src="http://www.khl.com{item-links/item-link[@id=2]/items/item/derived-files/preview}"/>
            <img src="http://www.khl.com/other_files/newsletters/spacer-new.gif" width="10" height="110" align="left"></img>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </a>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(content/item/standfirst,0,120)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      <xsl:text>...</xsl:text>
    </td>


  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="data-item" mode="access-newsQ">


    <xsl:variable name="title">
      <xsl:call-template name="replaceTitle">
        <xsl:with-param name="title" select="content/item/title"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="path">
      <xsl:call-template name="detail_path">
        <xsl:with-param name="item" select="current()"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <tr>
      <td width="250">
        <a class="headLineLink2" href="http://www.khl.com{$path}/{link}{$title}?nltr=rw">
          <strong>
            <xsl:value-of select="name" />
          </strong>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <td width="110" valign="top" class="tumbImage">
      <a href="http://www.khl.com{$path}/{link}{$title}?nltr=rw">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="item-links/item-link[@id=466]/items/item[1]">
            <img border="0" width="110" height="80" align="left" src="http://www.khl.com{item-links/item-link[@id=466]/items/item/derived-files/preview}"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <img border="0" width="110" height="80" align="left" src="http://www.khl.com{item-links/item-link[@id=2]/items/item/derived-files/preview}"/>
            <img src="http://www.khl.com/other_files/newsletters/spacer-new.gif" width="10" height="110" align="left"></img>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </a>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(content/item/standfirst,0,120)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      <xsl:text>...</xsl:text>
    </td>


  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="data-item" mode="access-newsN">

    <xsl:variable name="title">
      <xsl:call-template name="replaceTitle">
        <xsl:with-param name="title" select="content/item/title"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="path">
      <xsl:call-template name="detail_path">
        <xsl:with-param name="item" select="current()"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <tr>
      <td width="250">
        <a class="headLineLink2" href="http://www.khl.com{$path}/{link}{$title}?nltr=rw">
          <strong>
            <xsl:value-of select="name" />
          </strong>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <td width="110" valign="top" class="tumbImage">
      <a href="http://www.khl.com{$path}/{link}{$title}?nltr=rw">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="item-links/item-link[@id=466]/items/item[1]">
            <img border="0" width="110" height="80" align="left" src="http://www.khl.com{item-links/item-link[@id=466]/items/item/derived-files/preview}"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <img border="0" width="110" height="80" align="left" src="http://www.khl.com{item-links/item-link[@id=2]/items/item/derived-files/preview}"/>
            <img src="http://www.khl.com/other_files/newsletters/spacer-new.gif" width="10" height="110" align="left"></img>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </a>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(content/item/standfirst,0,120)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      <xsl:text>...</xsl:text>
    </td>


  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="data-item" mode="top-story">

    <xsl:variable name="title">
      <xsl:call-template name="replaceTitle">
        <xsl:with-param name="title" select="content/item/title"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="path">
      <xsl:call-template name="detail_path">
        <xsl:with-param name="item" select="current()"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <td valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="tumbImage">
      <a href="http://www.khl.com{$path}/{link}{$title}?nltr=wd">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="item-links/item-link[@id=466]/items/item[1]">
            <img border="0" width="200" height="146" src="http://www.khl.com{item-links/item-link[@id=466]/items/item/derived-files/preview}"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <img border="0" width="200" height="146" src="http://www.khl.com{item-links/item-link[@id=2]/items/item/derived-files/preview}"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

      </a>
    </td>

    <td valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
      <span class="headLineLink">
        <a href="http://www.khl.com{$path}/{link}{$title}?nltr=wd">
          <strong>
            <xsl:value-of select="name" />
          </strong>
        </a>
      </span>
      <p>
        <span class="toparticlemaintext">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring(content/item/standfirst,0,282)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </span>
        <a class="moreLink" href="http://www.khl.com{$path}/{link}{$title}?nltr=wd">View article »</a>
      </p>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="data-item" mode="other">

    <xsl:variable name="title">
      <xsl:call-template name="replaceTitle">
        <xsl:with-param name="title" select="content/item/title"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="path">
      <xsl:call-template name="detail_path">
        <xsl:with-param name="item" select="current()"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <td>
      <a href="http://www.khl.com{$path}/{link}{$title}?nltr=wd">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="item-links/item-link[@id=466]/items/item[1]">
            <img border="0" width="130" height="80" src="http://www.khl.com{item-links/item-link[@id=466]/items/item/derived-files/preview}"/>
          </xsl:when>

          <xsl:otherwise>
            <img border="0" width="130" height="80" src="http://www.khl.com{item-links/item-link[@id=2]/items/item/derived-files/preview}"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
      <a class="headLineLink" href="http://www.khl.com{$path}/{link}{$title}?nltr=wd">
        <strong>
          <xsl:value-of select="name" />
        </strong>
      </a>
      <p>
        <span name="input-code">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring(content/item/standfirst,0,282)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
          <xsl:text> . . .</xsl:text>
        </span>
        <a class="moreLink" href="http://www.khl.com{$path}/{link}{$title}?nltr=wd">more</a>
      </p>
    </td>

  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML CODE:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<search-results>
  <size>0</size>  
  <start-index>1</start-index>  
  <end-index>1</end-index>  
  <page-no>1</page-no>  
  <no-of-pages>1</no-of-pages>  
  <items-per-page>0</items-per-page>  
  <forward>
    <action>/vyre4/pub_module/pageview4757_70?portal:componentId=16821&amp;portal:type=action&amp;portal:isSecure=false&amp;portal:portletMode=xml</action> 
  </forward>  
  <action-path>/vyre4/pub_module/pageview4757_70?portal:componentId=16821&amp;portal:type=action&amp;portal:isSecure=false&amp;portal:portletMode=xml</action-path>  
  <action-extensions>
    <add-to-basket>
      <order>&amp;addToBasket=order</order>  
      <bulk-edit>&amp;addToBasket=bulkEdit</bulk-edit> 
    </add-to-basket>  
    <sortable-attributes>
      <score>&amp;sortBy=score</score>  
      <name>&amp;sortBy=sort_name</name>  
      <creationDate>&amp;sortBy=sort_creationDate_t</creationDate>  
      <lastModifiedDate>&amp;sortBy=sort_lastModifiedDate_t</lastModifiedDate>  
      <viewCount>&amp;sortBy=viewCount</viewCount>  
      <orderCount>&amp;sortBy=orderCount</orderCount>  
      <ratingAverage>&amp;sortBy=ratingAverage</ratingAverage>  
      <creatorFamilyName>&amp;sortBy=sort_creatorFamilyName_s</creatorFamilyName>  
      <creatorFullName>&amp;sortBy=sort_creatorFullName_s</creatorFullName>  
      <creatorGivenName>&amp;sortBy=sort_creatorGivenName_s</creatorGivenName>  
      <creatorUserName>&amp;sortBy=sort_creatorUserName_s</creatorUserName>  
      <lastModifierFamilyName>&amp;sortBy=sort_lastModifierFamilyName_s</lastModifierFamilyName>  
      <lastModifierFullName>&amp;sortBy=sort_lastModifierFullName_s</lastModifierFullName>  
      <lastModifierGivenName>&amp;sortBy=sort_lastModifierGivenName_s</lastModifierGivenName>  
      <lastModifierUserName>&amp;sortBy=sort_lastModifierUserName_s</lastModifierUserName>  
      <att869>&amp;sortBy=sort_att869_s</att869>  
      <att10>&amp;sortBy=sort_att10_s</att10>  
      <att871>&amp;sortBy=sort_att871_s</att871>  
      <att870>&amp;sortBy=sort_att870_s</att870>  
      <att5>&amp;sortBy=sort_att5_s</att5>  
      <att8>&amp;sortBy=sort_att8_t</att8> 
    </sortable-attributes>  
    <sort-directions>
      <asc>&amp;orderBy=asc</asc>  
      <desc>&amp;orderBy=desc</desc> 
    </sort-directions>  
    <items-per-page>&amp;itemsPerPage=</items-per-page>  
    <do-redirect>&amp;doRedirect=</do-redirect>  
    <page-no>&amp;pageNo=</page-no>  
    <previous-actions/> 
  </action-extensions>  
  <search-term>+(+(+active:true +att7:1 +att8:[0 TO $current_date] +(ITEM_LINK_DEF641:$current_item_id OR ITEM_LINK_DEF642:$current_item_id OR ITEM_LINK_DEF643:$current_item_id OR ITEM_LINK_DEF644:$current_item_id OR ITEM_LINK_DEF645:$current_item_id OR ITEM_LINK_DEF646:$current_item_id OR ITEM_LINK_DEF647:$current_item_id OR ITEM_LINK_DEF648:$current_item_id OR ITEM_LINK_DEF649:$current_item_id OR ITEM_LINK_DEF650:$current_item_id OR ITEM_LINK_DEF652:$current_item_id OR ITEM_LINK_DEF669:$current_item_id OR ITEM_LINK_DEF670:$current_item_id or ITEM_LINK_DEF691:$current_item_id))) +locale:en -(ITEM_LINK_DEF9:57303 OR ITEM_LINK_DEF9:57302)</search-term>  
  <sorting>
    <first-sort-field>att8</first-sort-field>  
    <first-sort-field-direction>desc</first-sort-field-direction>  
    <second-sort-field>lastModifiedDate</second-sort-field>  
    <second-sort-field-direction>desc</second-sort-field-direction> 
  </sorting>  
  <items/> 
</search-results>
```

Comment: What does your input XML look like?

Comment: Hi XML is fine as all the data is being pulled out and it is too long to print in this comment EDIT: posted above

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that there was a problem with your XML. I was pointing out that we need some XML to test and make sense of your 509 lines of XSLT.

Comment: sorry - xml has been added to the main question due to rating being under 10

Comment: Editing it into the main question is the right thing to do anyway, regardless of your reputation.  Code in comments doesn't work well because you lose the formatting.

Comment: Thanks - sorry I'm new

Answer (score 0):

XSLT code must be well-formed XML. That means you can't split the start-table tag into one template and the end-table tag into another; each template must be balanced.

I haven't looked at your stylesheet in detail, but the usual fix is to move the `<table></table>` pair up a level, wrapping them around the `<xsl:apply-templates>` which generates the table's contents.

Comment: I thought this is probably the case. but I cannot seem to find it. I will keep searching but unfortunately there is no compiler. So any alteration i make to the code I have preview manually and it's taking me an age.

Comment: Try (temporarily) simplifying your stylesheet as far as you can while still provoking the problem. That should help you discover where the mismatch is occurring.

Comment: Note that stylesheets are generally easier to debug when written in rule-driven style (templates xsl:apply-templates and matching) rather than pull style (one massive template). Smaller chunks of code are easier to read and understand, and to keep balanced. And FAR easier to maintain. If nothing else, consider dividing it up into named templates and using xsl:call-template to invoke them as subroutines, to make the code more modular and readable...